# Discord.py mutecommand with remove roles

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a temporary mute command that will remove your roles and give you a mute role and when the time is up - return your old roles. I know how to write a simple mute command, but this is a bit more complex. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary that will store muted members (you can then change it to use a database - e.g MongoDB) and use [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop) to check if it's time to unmute someone.

```py
muted_members = {}

@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member, time : int): # for example in minutes
    roles = member.roles[1:] # first role is always @everyone which cannot be removed (that's why we start with second item in list)
    unmute_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=time)
    muted_members.update({member.id : {"channel" : ctx.channel.id, "roles": roles, "time": unmute_time}}) # adding everything to dictionary

    await member.remove_roles(*roles) # removing all roles

    mute_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Muted") # searching for role named "Muted"
    await member.add_roles(mute_role) # adding mute role

    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been muted for **{time} minutes**.")


@tasks.loop(seconds=10) # looping every 10 seconds
async def mute_check():
    for user_id in muted_members:
        info = muted_members[user_id]

        if info["time"] < datetime.datetime.now(): # checking if anyone should be unmuted
            channel = await client.fetch_channel(info["channel"])
            guild = channel.guild
            member = await guild.fetch_member(user_id)

            mute_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await member.remove_roles(mute_role) # removing "Muted" role

            await member.add_roles(*info["roles"]) # adding old roles
            
            muted_members.pop(user_id) # deleting user from dictionary
            await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has been unmuted.")
            break

mute_check.start()
```